# Stream Elements PUT Request

Tags: php, curl

Good Afternooon all,

Please can someone give me a example of a PUT request? i have seen a couple online but i can not seam to get any to work.... I am trying to create an app for my live streaming channel, below is what i am trying to use PUT for.

Here is the DEV link to the API: https://dev.streamelements.com

So the URL would be: https://api.streamelements.com/kappa/v2

the PUT i need is the following

```
/points/{channel}/{user}/{amount}

Media type: application/json
```

so i understand the url in full if it was a get:

(api.streamelements.com/kappa/v2/points/channe id removed/username removed)

That gives me my points on a selected channel but to add or remove points it has to be a PUT and i have no idea on how to use it, so if anyone could give me some example of the above i could learn from it and do all the other requests myself

Many Thanks for your time

Kev (TADS)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to be familiar with HTTP clients such as Guzzle or other clients that implements Psr7 interface.

In your case your code should looks like:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$client->put('https://api.streamelements.com/kappa/v2/REST_OF_URL', [
    'headers'         => ['X-Foo' => 'Bar'],
    'body'            => [
        'field1' => 'value1',
        // ...
    ],
    'timeout'         => 10
]);
```

Obviously I'm assuming that you know how to include the Guzzle library to your project using Composer or standalone include.

Comment: Today i managed to work out how to do this just using PHP and curl like i needed. Thank you for you reply tho